# VBA User Defined Function in Excel breaking for unexpected large values within loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Update - after further testing I see that the value of UniqueLength is turning into 2^(X-1)+1, where X is the number of results. I still don't understand why that's happening though...

I have a function that a user can enter on a line of Excel (in a predetermined format and in a specific column) called ScoreQ2().  The function takes an ID from column B, searches every line of column B that ID, and checks those lines for a couple criteria.  Ultimately, it returns a score (not necessary for you to understand, but it's grading something).

It works for most of the items, but for some reason it breaks on a few larger values.  Specifically, it breaks on the 3 IDs that have the most rows that meet the criteria ("2 - Red Chemical...") and cells(i, 24) = 200 .  The data set is about 13K lines, and these IDs have 21, 15, or 11 responses in that set.

In my code, you'll see I declare an array from 1 to 5000. I don't know why I'd need more than 21 in this.  When I change the array size from 500 to 5,000, the ID with 13 responses start to work. And adding another 0 to 50,000 makes the 15 response item work.  However, no acceptable size of array would work with the 21 responses (I kept adding 0s until it broke).

I realize that I do some really weird things here, like declaring the first 19 values of my array. For some reason I had to declare a few, and this is where I ended up...

I tried stepping through using a set example from the 21-size ID.  It eventually broke on "Unique(UniqueLength) = Cells(i, 23)" saying error 9, subscript out of range.  That's how I got the idea to increase the array size from 500 to 5,000.

I could post a couple examples here, but I'm not sure how to, or if it's necessary.  Let me know if that would help.

```
Function ScoreQ2()

Dim Max As Integer
Dim Min As Integer
Dim Unique(1 To 5000) As Integer
Dim UniqueLength As Integer
Dim NewUnique As Boolean
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim ResultID As Long
Dim question As Long


ResultID = 0
UniqueLength = 1
NewUnique = True
Max = 0
Min = 200
question = 0
Unique(1) = 500
Unique(2) = 500
Unique(3) = 500
Unique(4) = 500
Unique(5) = 500
Unique(6) = 500
Unique(7) = 500
Unique(8) = 500
Unique(9) = 500
Unique(10) = 500
Unique(11) = 500
Unique(12) = 500
Unique(13) = 500
Unique(14) = 500
Unique(15) = 500
Unique(16) = 500
Unique(17) = 500
Unique(18) = 500
Unique(19) = 500


LastRow = Application.Caller.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(Application.Caller.Row, Application.Caller.Column - 15) Then
    ResultID = ResultID + 1
        If StrComp(Cells(i, 11), "2 - Red Chemical_Reduced Range") = 0 Then
        question = question + 1

        If Cells(i, 24) = 200 Then
            NewUnique = True
            For j = 1 To UniqueLength
                If Cells(i, 23) = Unique(j) Then
                NewUnique = False
                j = UniqueLength
                End If

                If NewUnique = True Then
                Unique(UniqueLength) = Cells(i, 23)
                UniqueLength = UniqueLength + 1

                    If Cells(i, 23) > Max Then
                    Max = Cells(i, 23)
                    End If

                    If Cells(i, 23) < Min Then
                    Min = Cells(i, 23)
                    End If

                End If
           Next j
        Else
        End If
    Else

    End If
Else
End If
Next i

If UniqueLength > 3 Then
If Max - Min > 99 Then
    ScoreQ2 = 3
Else
    ScoreQ2 = 2
End If
ElseIf UniqueLength > 2 Then
ScoreQ2 = 1

Else
ScoreQ2 = 0
End If


End Function
```

Comment: For starters, always use `Long` for a row counter, not `Integer`.

Comment: If this code is in a regular module then whenever you use `Cells()` by itself it will default to the active sheet, so if the sheet with your formula on it isn't active it will return false information.

Comment: Do you mean UniqueLength? I tried it, but no change.  Part of my confusion with all this is that UniqueLength should never really go over the # of responses.  So, for the 21 responses, it shouldn't be higher than 21.

Comment: Tim, is there something I could do to stop that problem? That said, not sure if I'd ever encounter that here. Thanks.

Comment: Another suggestion is to change the line "j = UniqueLength" to "Exit For" as it's more clear.  This won't fix the problem, but it's easier to understand.

Comment: Also, if you want to notify the person that you are trying to communicate with through comments, you need to use the @ symbol followed by their name.  You get notifications of comments on your own question, but not on other ones you've commented on unless you are tagged.

Comment: And Tim was referring to the "LastRow" variable in his comment to use Long.  An integer can only go up to about 32k, but Excel can hold many more rows than this.

Comment: To solve the other problem he mentioned, you need to use "Sheets("mySheet").Cells()" instead of just "Cells()".  Obviously put in the actual name of your sheet.  You could use the "Application.Caller.Worksheet" construct also.  It'd probably be best to just define a worksheet variable and then use that variable in front of all the cells() calls.

Comment: @OpiesDad thanks, I was trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but the problem is in your loop constructs.

The first time that (i,24) = 200 your for loop is

```
For j = 1 To 1
```

and only runs once, with the value of UniqueLength = 1.

If the condition

```
  If Cells(i, 23) = Unique(1)
```

is evaluated to false, then you will be adding 1 to UniqueLength, so it is now 2.

The next time you have the for loop of

```
For j = 1 To 2
```

and a value of 2 for UniqueLength.

This then checks for

```
If Cells(i, 23) = Unique(1) and then runs again and checks if it is Unique(2).
```

If neither of these is true (and it will never be true, because you set the first 19 items of the Unique array to 500, which is likely not a possible value), then you will increment UniqueLength twice, so that it is now 4.

The next time, your for loop is

```
For j = 1 To 4
```

and you will be incrementing UniqueLength by 4.

This leads to the behavior that UniqueLength = 2^X.

As to how to fix this problem, it is unclear what you are trying to do, so I'm not sure what to say.

First, the reason that you are having to declare values in your array is that when you first start, the array is empty.

Then you run a check against the array:

```
If Cells(i, 23) = Unique(j)
```

but Unique(1) is empty!!

You need to fix how you are looking at the array.  (Note: there are probably better ways to do this, but this is the quickest fix I could think of)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("mySheet")
    UniqueLength = 0

```
....more code (do not declare the array values)

If ws.Cells(i, 24) = 200 Then
        NewUnique = True
        For j = 1 To UniqueLength 'When 0, this will not run the loop
            If ws.Cells(i, 23) = Unique(j) Then
                NewUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If NewUnique = True Then
            UniqueLength = UniqueLength + 1
            Unique(UniqueLength) = ws.Cells(i, 23)

.....rest of code
```

Obviously, you will need to fix the part at the end where you set the score, and I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but this will at least run through without looping exponentially.